# App crash due to uncloseable FileStream

Tags: .net, exception, filestream, flush

Just prior to calling the Close() method on a FileStream object, I unplug the underlying USB drive.  The Close() method will throw an exception when it attempts to flush unwritten data.  If I squelch the exception (catch, but don't re-throw) the finalizer is invoked an arbitrary amount of time later.  It will attempt to flush unwritten data but encounters the same error, causing the application to terminate.

Is there a standard way to handle a failing Close() invocation?  It seems that if Close() encounters an error you either 1) leak a file handle or 2) cause the application to terminate, neither of which is acceptable.

Comment: Similar to what speising is suggesting, when you first capture the Close exception, try calling Dispose in in the exception handler, using a nested try-catch to avoid loss of control if it also throws an exception. Don't know if this will work, but worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

if instead of calling `Close()`, you call `Dispose()`, or wrap your code in a `using`, you should be able to avoid the exception from GC, since the finalizer will not try to dispose the stream anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GC.SuppressFinalize to suppress the finalizer from executing so later when the object is garbage collected you will not get an error.

Comment: I considered that, but my impression was that this was not a best practice, no?  Instead, SuppressFinalize should invoked from inside Dispose() and be passed 'this'.  Since I don't have access to the FileStream class, this would not be possible.

Comment: You can pass the instance of the filestream that you are using instead of 'this'. It will work the same. The SuppressFinalize is a static method and can take any object as an argument.